# How can I fetch unique ID of a Google form drop down?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to automate Google form filling using Excel macro.

I need the unique ids for drop down, which are available for web forms (through Inspect Element).

How can I get IDs for Google form drop downs?

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc/viewform"
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    doc.getElementByI(" xxxxxxx").data-value = 1 Dhagera
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]